# Assuming a variable is imaginary

Tags: assumptions

I am confused how to assume a variable is pure imaginary. As a test example, I used the code

```
Assuming[{ x \[Element] I Reals}, Simplify[x + Conjugate[x]]]
```

In the above, "I" means the imaginary unit. I find that it does not return me 0, but just

```
x + Conjugate[x]
```

How shall I let $x$ to be pure imaginary? Many thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This needs `FullSimplify`.

```
FullSimplify[x + Conjugate[x], Re[x] == 0]
```

> `0`